# Qt C++ - How to pass data from a worker thread to main thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am trying to perform interthread communication in Qt (C++). I have a worker thread which does some calculations and I want the workerthread to return its results to the main thread when done. I therefor use a connect, I know thanks to debugging, that the signal is successfully being emit but that it is the slot that isn t being executed and I don t understand why.

The relevant pieces of code:

```
webcamClass::webcamClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{  
    workerThread = new QThread(this);
    workerClassObj = new workerClass();

    //connect for image
    connect(workerClassObj, SIGNAL(mySignal(QPixmap)), this, SLOT(mySlot(QPixmap)));
     //connect(&workerClassObj, workerClass::mySignal(QPixmap), this, webcamClass::mySlot(QPixmap));


    connect( workerThread, SIGNAL(started()), workerClassObj, SLOT(getImage()) );
    workerClassObj->moveToThread(workerThread);


}

void webcamClass:: foo()
{

      workerThread->start();
}

void workerClass::getImage()
{
    qint64 successFailWrite;
    QImage img;
    QPixmap pixmap;

    ... do some stuff with pixmap...

    qDebug()<<"going to emit result";

    emit mySignal(pixmap);

    qDebug()<<"emitted";
}


void webcamClass::mySlot(QPixmap p)
{qDebug()<<"this message should be displayed"; }
```

The corresponding header files:

```
   class workerClass : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    private:

    public:
        explicit workerClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);


    signals:
        void mySignal(QPixmap);
    };



webcamClass::webcamClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit webcamClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);

public slots:
    void mySlot(QPixmap p);

private:

    QThread *workerThread;
    workerClass *workerClassObj;


};
```

The code above just outputs:

```
going to emit result
emitted
```

but unfortunately doesn t output `this message should be displayed`.

webcamClass belongs to the parent thread, while workerClass belngs to -you guessed it- the worker thread.

Could someone explain how to setup my connect so that mySlot() gets triggered?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried moving     connect(workerClassObj, SIGNAL(mySignal(QPixmap)), this, SLOT(mySlot(QPixmap)));
 to before moveToThread call? BTW, if you use qt5 you better move to the new signal/slot connections (https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)

Comment: Did you declare `mySignal` using `signals:`?

Comment: @AMA updated my post

Comment: @JLev I know about the new syntax, as you can see it is there, the line just below in comments. Yes, I tried moving it before the moveToThread, same result

Comment: Where do you call `webcamClass::foo()`?  Also, your attempt at the new signal/slot syntax appear to be incorrect.

Comment: worker class does not have a slot called getImage(). In fact, it doesnt have any slots at all.

Comment: @G.M. I call foo() when you press a pushbutton on the GUI. Yes I know that the syntax for the new connect is incorrect, I couldn't get it straight so just commented it out and went for the old syntax.

Comment: @Hafnernuss indeed the slot is in the parent thread and belongs to the object which belngs to the parent not the worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you pasted in pastebin.com/UpPfrNEt you have a `getVideoFrame` method that uses `while (1)`. If this method is called, it runs all the time and blocks the event loop from handling signals. You can solve it in many ways, I think the best practice will be to replace the while(1) with something else.

Comment: @LandonZeKepitelOfGreytBritn -- It's not simply a case of removing the `while` loop.  The thread receiving queued signals *must* have an active `Qt` event loop.

Comment: You can try adding `QApplication::processEvents()` inside the loop.

Comment: I'll accept your answer, it puts the finger on an aspect I didn't think about and an issue I would have faced either case. The actual error in my code was linked to a spelling mistake... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I highly encourage you to use the new Signal Slot syntax:

`connect( SOURCEINSTANCE, &CLASS::SIGNAL, TARGETINSTANCE, &CLASS::SLOT );`

In your case, that could be:

`connect( workerClassObj, &workerClass::mySignal, this, &webcamClass::mySlot );`

Specificallyfor your case, if you want to pass Signals and Slots between threads, you have to be careful. First, check the connection type for the connect call, its acutally the last parameter.

`connect( workerClassObj, &workerClass::mySignal, this, &webcamClass::mySlot, Qt::QueuedConnection );`

For a detailed explanation look here:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

If you want to pass custom types, you have to declare them as metatypes first.
Add e.G. this in your constructor:

qRegisterMetaType("MyDataType");

Please make sure, that your custom datatype has a default constructor and be aware that afaik, references cannot be passed across threads.

Comment: trying the new syntax gives me `invalid use of non-static member function 'void workerClassObj::mySignal(QPixmap)'`.

Comment: Could you post the code that you used? Im pretty sure you forgot the '&'

Comment: try this: 
connect(recognitionClObj, &recognitionClass::signPixMapLandmarks, this, &webcamClass::emitUpdateGuiLandmarks, Qt::QueuedConnection);

Comment: shouldnt you emit signPixMapLandmarks instead of gottenVideoFrame?

Comment: Could you update your main post to the actual code? Its way easier for others to help

Comment: I made a very stupid mistake... Now it works, it was a spelling mistake. I upvoted your answer, thanks for your input!

Comment: Thanks and im glad you caught it.